# PHP cURL (Error: 28: Resolving timed out after milliseconds)

Tags: php, curl, ssl

Я пытаюсь использовать cURL в php, но возникает ошибка, и ничего в ответ не возвращается:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Resolving timed out after 5514 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
28: Resolving timed out after 5514 milliseconds
```

Код такой:

```
<?php

$url = "https://example.com/rest/checksms/9502ec34-5348-4096-838a-e7ac0cce9d74";
$cert_password = '123456789';

$curl = curl_init();
if ($curl === false)
{
   throw new Exception(' cURL init failed');
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/home/redmine_dev/curl/client_smsgate-in.pem");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $cert_password);

$result = curl_exec($curl);


if ( ! $result) {
    print curl_errno($curl) .': '. curl_error($curl);
}
$result = curl_multi_getcontent ($curl);

echo "\n".'Login OK'."\n".'[result ===8<===>'."\n".$result."\n".'<===>8=== result]'."\n";

curl_close($curl);
```

При том, что если использовать просто cURL из командной строки:
`curl "https://example.com/rest/checksms/9502ec34-5348-4096-838a-e7ac0cce9d74" --cert ./client_smsgate-in.pem:123456789 -k`

Домен `https://example.com/` резолвится в сети, пинги проходят. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

UPDATE: При этом, заметил, данная ошибка возникает как запустить скрипт первый раз, если после завершения сразу запустить его снова, вываливается это: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure.
`php -v`:

```
PHP 5.6.20-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Apr 27 2016 11:26:05)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies`
```

`curl --version`:

```
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1k zlib/1.2.8     libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3  pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz  TLS-SRP
```

`httpd -v`:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb  9 2016 17:28:49
```

Comment: Увеличение таймаута не решает проблему?

Comment: @VenZell, нет, ставил 500, не помогло. При этом, заметил, данная ошибка возникает как запустить скрипт первый раз, если после завершения сразу запустить его снова, вываливается это: `error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Comment: Попробуйте добавить опцию `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST` со значением `TLSv1` и проверьте, разрешены ли у вас в Apache ssl-соединения. В частности TLS.

Comment: Добавьте обновление из комментария в вопрос. Укажите в вопросе версию php, curl и apache

Comment: @VenZell, поставил `TLSv1` не помогло. Апач тут не использую, запускаю просто скрипт из командной строки

Comment: Я просто из вашего вопроса не понял, что возвращает запуск из командной строки. Я полагал, ошибка касается только вызова в PHP.

Comment: @VenZell, запускаю скрипт из командной строки: `$ php rest.php`. Возвращает он мне вот это: `Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.100.0.175...
* Connected to smsgate_in_dd (10.100.0.175) port 9443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/redmine_dev/curl/crt.crt
  CApath: /home/redmine_dev/curl/client_smsgate-in.pem
* error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
35: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
[result ======>

<====== result]
`